# TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a slider with 3 images that work perfectly in vanilla javascript and I am trying to make it work in React.js. After  3 images I got this error. I understand that maybe the problem is because of the jsx is rendered after the code but I don't know how to work around it and it also tells me that let slideInterval variable is declared but never read, when I place the cursor on it, please help.

```
        <prev> import React from 'react';
        import '../style.css';
        import photo1 from '../images/01.jpg';
        import photo2 from '../images/02.jpg';
        import photo3 from '../images/03.jpg';


      const Slider2 = () => {


      const slides = [photo1, photo2, photo3]<code>

      <prev>const auto = true; // Auto scroll
            const intervalTime = 3000;
            let slideInterval;
           //const slides =  document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
           const nextSlide = () => {
           // Get current class
            //console.log(slides);
            const current = document.querySelector(".current");
           // Remove current class
           current.classList.remove("current");
           // Check for next slide
           if (current.nextElementSibling) {
           // Add current to next sibling
           current.nextElementSibling.classList.add("current");
           } else {
           // Add current to start

           slides[0].classList.add("current");

           setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove("current"));
           }
           };<code>
           <prev>if (auto) {
           // Run next slide at interval time
           slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, intervalTime);
            }

           return (
           <div class="slider">
           <div class="slide current">
           <img src={slides[0]} />
           </div>
           <div class="slide  ">
           <img src={slides[1]} />
           </div>
           <div class="slide  ">
           <img src={slides[2]} />
           </div>
           </div>
           );
           };

           export default Slider2;                 <code>
```

[image]

Comment: As per the code, slides contains the imported images, which is not an `img` element. hence there is no `classList`.

Comment: it works for the first loop, it shows all the images, the problem is after the last one it crashes trying to initiate again

Comment: Panther comment made me think in the solution

Answer (score 0):

Check if `slides[0]` and `classList` undefined before adding,

```
if(slides[0] && slides[0].classList ){
  slides[0].classList.add("current");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add an id to the img tag and add this line of code:
document.getElementById('img1').classList.add('current');

instead of slides[0].classList.add("current"); and solved.